# Angular lifecycle: How do I execute a javascript function AFTER Angular has been initialized?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

I'm supposed to use this third party framework and have to initialize it after Angular has initialized.

I've tried adding it to my index.html:

```
<body>
  ...
<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
        console.log('DKFDS Initialized', DKFDS);
        DKFDS.init();
    });
</script>
</body>
```

but that doesn't work.

So I tried adding it to ngOnInit() in app.component.ts:

```
ngOnInit() {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
        console.log('DKFDS Initialized', DKFDS);
        DKFDS.init();
    });
}
```

still no luck :-(

The only way I can get it to work is by using jQuery to call the init() function:

```
ngOnInit() {
  $(() => {
    console.log('DKFDS Initialized', DKFDS);
      DKFDS.init();
    });
}
```

EDIT: I've also tried ngAfterViewInit() with the same disappointing result...

So my question is: How do I make this work in a pure Angular app without jQuery?

I've made a stackblitz to try to illustrate the issue. A menu should popup by clicking the "Overflow menu": https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ubsvkt

Comment: have you tried ngAfterViewInit ?

Comment: Call your function in `ngAfterViewInit ` becasue `DOMContentLoaded` equivalent to `ngAfterViewInit`

Comment: Updated OP: ngAfterViewInit() didn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the [updated](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ubsvkt?file=package.json) stackblitz example, now it works,

You can find the dkfds dependency installed, and now the dropdown menu works as expexted. The problem was Angular doesn't know what that library was. [Here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dkfds) is the dkfds npm page, you can install into your angular project with `npm install --save dkfds`

Answer (score 1):

In such a case, you can initialize the third party lib inside **ngAfterViewChecked**

```
ngAfterViewChecked() { 
      DKFDS.init();
}
```

For angular Lifecycle Hooks refer: https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks

Comment: I tried that but then DKFDS.init() was called all the time... :-)

Comment: @CJe , You should use a flag variable to check if it is initialized once.

Answer (score 0):

Add a **setTimeOut** to make it work like charm. Or use **ngAfterViewInit()** angular hook.

```
ngOnInit() {
  setTimeOut(() => {
   document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
      console.log('DKFDS Initialized', DKFDS);
      DKFDS.init();
    });
  });   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can show/hide the "overflow-menu-inner" div by toggling  `showOverflowMenu` on button click.

Try like this:

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h6t2hn?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html)**

```
<button (click)="showOverflowMenu = !showOverflowMenu"
  ...
</button>

    <div class="overflow-menu-inner" id="overflow1" *ngIf="showOverflowMenu">

        <ul class='overflow-list'>
            <li><button>Option 1</button></li>
            <li><button>Option 2</button></li>
            <li><a href='#'>Option 3 as link</a></li>
            <li><button>Option 4 is longer text</button></li>
        </ul>

    </div>
```

Comment: This works nicely :-) The issue is that the overflow menu is not the only component of the DKFDS framework. So I'll have to do workarounds for the others too :-/

Comment: This is the way things work in Angular, why do want to do it in jquery way?

Comment: Oh I don't want to do it using jQuery - definitely not. That was my entire issue - how to get it working w/o jQuery :-)